# Unique key for 3D interger coordinates to insert into a std::unordered_set

Tags: c++, hash, set, unordered-set

I have a stream of 3D integer coordinates that correspond to voxels and thus are aligned on a grid. I want to figure out if the current processed triplet is already existing in order to filter duplicates. I was able to build a simple solution to my problem with a `std::set`. Let `x` `y` `z` be 3 `int` and `registry` be a `std::set< std::array<int, 3> >`. I made a function that return a `bool` like that

```
std::array<int, 3> key = {x, y, z};
return registry.insert(key).second;
```

But this is far to be optimized in term of computation time. Reading documentation and SO topics I understand that an `unordered_set` should be more appropriated. Indeed there is no need to sort anything here. In addition I guess that using a `array<int,3>` as key is not efficient for comparison at `insert` time.

An `unordered_set` requires a hash function. Studying hash functions I found `boost::hash_combine` as well as other options.

How can I use an `unordered_set` efficiently in my situation? The key point is being as fast as possible. I don't need to access to values and I don't need to make any special computations.

Comment: What is the range of your `int`? Note that as stated in the answer, hash collusions are not an issue if there are not so much. If it were such an issue, hash tables will never be used ... Collusions slow down the process a very little bit, but result is correct

Comment: That is the issue. I don't know in advance the bounding box. Otherwise the problem would be simplified  using a `vector<bool>` and attributing an ID to each voxel. I understand why few collisions are not a problem for storing e.g. hashed passwords but in my case I can't understand why it is not a problem.

Comment: I don't understand why you think there is a problem. Int arrays are stored, hash password is a mean to accelerate the process to find the location of a given array,  or to find that an array was not stored. Duplicate passwords slow down the process, nothing more

Comment: Gotcha! This was not my understanding. In my mind if two triplets share different positions but the same hash only one can be inserted and the other one is wrongly mistaken with the first one. But actually the hash is just a help to find the triplets then the actual values are compared in case of collision. That makes a lot of sense actually.

Comment: You got it. You can check if performance is improved and edit your question if it is the case. The fact that hashing is suitable was indicated in the answer. You may accept it if you get good performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question. My initial question was ill-formed but thank to @Damien I understood how the hash was used into an `std::unordered_*`. I used `boost`

```
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
```

And I defined my `registry` as follow

```
typedef std::array<I32,3> Array;
std::unordered_set<Array, boost::hash<Array> >
```

And I gained ~33% of computation time.

Answer (score 1):

Whooooa don't be using vector for things like this. It dynamically allocates. You are *annihilating* your program's cache potential.

There are only three `int`s ever so just make a `struct` that has three `int`s in it. Or pass a `std::array<int, 3>` around.

Then measure it again and see what happens. You might find that the set is now fine. If not, well, you can create a hash for three `int`s. Don't bother trying to come up with a hash function that always provides unique values, though, as that literally defeats the purpose of a hash function.

If that's still too slow then you might want to consider coming up with a proper algorithm for this, seeing as both set and unordered_set will still be dynamically allocating nodes. That's just one level of indirection rather than the two that you've got now, but zero is better than none.

Comment: Indeed an `array` makes sense. My bad. However I benchmarked it with an `array` and I found 0 gain. Why do you tell me to do not bother with a unique key? If I don't have a unique key I will have collisions and thus a bad filter.